# Php File uploading not working

Tags: php

The html file

```
<html>
<head><title> Form Uploading </title></head>
<body>
<h3>File upload </h3>
Select a File <BR />
<Form action ="upload.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name ="file" sieze = "50" >
<input type ="submit" value = "Upload File">
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

The php file

```
<?php
if($_FILES[ 'file'][ 'name' ] != ""){
       copy ( $_FILES[ 'file'][ 'name' ], "C:\Users\Acasa\Desktop".$_FILES[ 'file'][ 'name' ]) ;#or 
       #die( "Could not copy file!");
    echo $_FILES[ 'file'][ 'name' ];
}else{ 


echo "Sent File".$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name']."<BR />";
echo "Size File".$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'size']."<BR />";
echo "Type File".$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'type']."<BR />";
}
?>
```

Both are in the same dir.

I want to try the code from tutorialspoint.com 
but for some reason it`s not working...
I want to copy the uploaded file into another dir
they used function copy and not move_uploaded_file

Any suggestion why it`s not working?

Comment: **Don't use that tutorial**. It is obsolete and insecure.

Comment: Whenever something doesn't work, enable `error_reporting`. It'll give you two hints here.

Comment: Use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) with `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` instead of `copy`.

Comment: Yea it have some good parts and some bad parts...Any php site tutorial you know? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just have a look at http://php.net and search SO for questions.

Comment: `I want to copy the uploaded file into another dir they used function copy and not move_uploaded_file` so you want to do this the wrong way on purpose? Is this how you aim to learn PHP? Do you think this is a desirable skill for a programmer to have?

Comment: John Conade i am trying to understand why they used that instead of that , i am trying to see the diference , if i ask myself question why this and not that , this or that? I think this is a good way to learn.
I want to learn PHP because is easier to make scripts than JSP but i prefer JSP and i will learn JSP but not now.

Comment: Oh please, don't put code in comments, but edit your own question *or* write an answer yourself.

Comment: ok I will keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the move_uploaded_file() function instead of copy() :

```
<?php
if ( move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] , 
     "YOUR_PATH".$your_file_name ) )
   echo "Download completed";
else
   echo "Error";
?>
```

Don't forget to check format, size, etc.. before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($_FILES[ 'file'][ 'name' ] != ""){
       move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES[ 'file'][ 'tmp_name' ], "C:\Users\Acasa\Desktop".$_FILES[ 'file'][ 'name' ]) or 
       die( "Could not copy file!");
}else{ 
    die("no file found");
}

echo "Sent File: ".$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'name']."<BR />";
echo "Size File: ".$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'size']."<BR />";
echo "Type File: ".$_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'type']."<BR />";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working. You should use the move_uploaded_file() function instead of copy() :